# Acts_as_commentable_with_threading Ajax not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, post

I have done the implementation of threaded comments by using the  acts_as_commentable_with_threading gem and everything is fine but I cannot seem to be able to implement ajax for it.

I have implemented in comments that were not threaded but with threaded comments I don't seem to be able to do it.

```
 $('#comments').append('<%= j render @comment %>');
```

This line is the problem but I don't know how to make it work.
If I change :

```
$('#comments').append('Hi!');
```

It works so there is no ajax fault it must be the `<%= j render @comment %>`
The comments get created but it doesn't get appended to the page. 
I get this error

```
 POST http://localhost:3000/comments 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I followed this tutorial for the implementation of the plain threaded comments http://dustinfisher.com/acts-as-commentable-with-threading-gem/

Please If you know let me now on where the problem is.

---

Edit
This error also pops in the terminal for commentable and new_comment
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `commentable' for #<#:0x0000000c396398>):

Answer (score 0):

This isn't tested. But after looking at the example you linked to. Its looks like you are missing the locals and instead of passing the variable maybe try passing a partial of the comment body/reply button.

```
$('#comments').append(<%= j render partial: "comments/comment_body", locals: {commentable: @beer, new_comment: @comment} %>);
```